# Vue.JS: Communication with component

Tags: vue.js

I have two component Header and AddUser component. Inside Header component I have a button that has function to show modal. And the modal is inside AddUser component like below.

Header.vue

```
<template>
    <header>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class="text-center btn-class">
            <button @click="showModal = true">Add Vehicle</button>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: 'Header',
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Title!!',
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Description!!',
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

AddUser.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
      <transition name="fade" appear>
         <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false"></div>
      </transition>
      <transition name="slide" appear>
         <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
            <h3>Enter your vehicle detail</h3>
            <div class="body">
                <form @submit="onSubmit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-btn form-group text-center">
                    <Button type="submit" text="Add" color="#2BA0A3" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </transition>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   import Button from './Button'
   export default {
       name: 'AddUser',
       data(){
           return {
               showModal: false,
               name: ''
           }
       },
       components: {
           Button
       },
       methods: {
           onSubmit(e){ 
               e.preventDefault()
               if(!this.name){
                   alert('Please enter name.')
               }
           },
       }
   }
</script>
```

And this is my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <Header  />
      <AddUser />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import AddUser from './components/AddUser'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    AddUser,
  }  
}
</script>
```

The code works perfectly if I put button inside AddUser.vue but I want to keep the button on Header.vue and want it work also. How can I make it both component to communicate?

Comment: You will need to emit an event from your `Header` component and listen for the event in your `AddUser` component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Comment: If you want specific examples then you will need to post your how your `Header` and `AddUser` components are related.  Are they siblings, parent and child, grandparent and grandchild, etc.

Comment: @bassxzero I have added my App.vue. I hope you got what you were trying to say. I am sorry if I didn't get you right. I am into vue from past two days so I might not understand what you are trying to get from me.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `showModal` variable to your `App.vue` and pass it to your `AddUser` component as a prop. Inside your `Header` and `AddUser` components you will need to update the `showModal` value by emitting a `show-modal-event` with the value true or false depending on if you want to show or hide the modal. Listen for the event in `App.vue` and update it's local data `showModal` value with the `$event`s value.

Here is an example. ** FYI this code isn't tested so there might be typos.

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
    <header>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class="text-center btn-class">
            <button @click="$emit('show-modal-event', true)">Add Vehicle</button>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: 'Header',
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Title!!',
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Description!!',
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**AddUser.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <transition name="fade" appear>
            <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="$emit('show-modal-event', false)"></div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="slide" appear>
            <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
                <h3>Enter your vehicle detail</h3>
                <div class="body">
                    <form @submit="onSubmit">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="form-btn form-group text-center">
                            <Button type="submit" text="Add" color="#2BA0A3" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Button from './Button'
export default {
    name: 'AddUser',
    data(){
        return {
            name: ''
        }
    },
    props: {
        showModal: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    components: {
        Button
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if(!this.name){
                alert('Please enter name.')
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <Header @show-modal-event="showModal=$event"  />
        <AddUser @show-modal-event="showModal=$event" :showModal="showModal" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import AddUser from './components/AddUser'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        Header,
        AddUser,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            showModal: false,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: It says 'Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "showModal"' it is on `AddUser`

Comment: @Gaurav I don't think you are using my version of `AddUser`. I think you are still using the old version. I'm not update the `showModal` variable in `AddUser`

Comment: `<div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="$emit('show-modal-event', false)"></div>`

Comment: I updated code, it did not give any error but it also didn't do anything on clicking Add Vehicle button

Comment: @Gaurav This code I posted works. https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-curie-8cj98 Here is a sandbox for it.